# Question on "difference(s) of opinion(s)"

Tags: usage

What is the correct expression in English? If various versions can be used, could you explain the usage differences and provide examples? Thanks:

- Difference of opinion
- Difference**s** of opinion
- Difference of opinion**s**
- Difference**s** of opinion**s**

Answer (score 2):

"Difference of opinion" and "differences of opinion" are both correct: "difference of opinion" is the singular, used when referring to a single disagreement — a single thing that people are disagreeing about — while "differences of opinion" is the plural, used when referring to multiple disagreements — multiple things that people are disagreeing about.

"Difference of opinions" and "differences of opinions" are both quite rare by comparison — less than one-twentieth as common, according to the Google Books Ngram Viewer [[link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=difference+of+opinion%2C+differences+of+opinion%2C+difference+of+opinions%2C+differences+of+opinions&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)] — and when they *do* occur, they're usually just variants of "difference of opinion" and "differences of opinion", respectively. That said, looking through [the Google Books hits for "difference of opinions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22difference+of+opinions%22&tbm=bks), I do see a few uses of "difference of opinions" to mean "differences of opinion", as well as a few chance occurrences that aren't quite of this expression (such as one where the "opinions" are expressed numerically and the "difference" denotes literal subtraction).